# Convert Photoshop HSL Adjustment layer to Color Matrix?

Tags: javascript, photoshop, easeljs, colormatrix, rainmeter

I'm having a nightmare with colour matrices. I'm using an adjustment layer in photoshop with the values `Hue: -37`, `Saturation: -25` which results in a nice pinky dawn colour:

[image: Photoshop Adjustment Layer]

I'm trying to use `EaselJS` to create my matrix based on the values in my HSL adjustment layer for Rainmeter (which can only use these), so I'm generating my matrix like so:

`new createjs.ColorMatrix().adjustColor(0, 0, -25, -37);`

See here: http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/ColorMatrix.html#method_adjustColor

This results in a bright green colour as you can see:

[image: Bright green]

Is there another way to generate my colour matrix? Can I convert A Photoshop adjustment layer to a colour matrix?
Could the difference in results be related to not having `Colorize` checked?

Comment: Please, use exactly same images for example.

Comment: @VallyN the images are the same. i'm just only applying the matrix to one layer in the second rather than the whole image

Comment: I know, that PS may use color correction. Maybe [ColorFilter](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/ColorFilter.html) will be better is this case.

Comment: @VallyN the software i'm using the end result of the matrix generation in can only use a colour matrix. ColorFilter does not generate me a matrix.

Comment: No thoughts in particular, but one. Try transposed matrix.

Comment: Any chance you can share your original image for testing?

Comment: @Lanny find the image here: http://www.firewatchgame.com/images/parallax/parallax1.png

Comment: I ran your basic ColorMatrix code in an isolated spike, and while it doesn't match the comp, it is in the right hue: http://screens.gskinner.com/lanny/Screen%20Shot%202016-03-14%20at%203.11.22%20PM.png http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/k6zjnys4/

Comment: @Lanny bizarre.. thank for trying this out. I was using the output from ColorMatrix() in the application i was using as my colour matrix.. Interesting that it's still not the same colour...

Comment: @Lanny figured it out. the JS library fills the matrix array top to bottom not left to right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this turned out to be fairly simple. The matrixes generated were correct with slight differences. These differences turned out to be because a Photoshop HSL adjustment layer also changes the `brightness` and `contrast`. I believe that `Lightness` is a function of `Brightness` and `Contrast` although I'm not sure how it is worked out so it's not easy to get it perfect. Trial and error basically.

The reason my colours were totally wrong before was down to the fact that the array generated by `ColorMatrix.js` fill the matrix top to bottom not left to right.

i.e.:

```
Array [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Becomes:

```
Matrix [[0, 2, 4, 6, 8],
        [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]]
```

Shortened for example, true colour matrix will be a 5x5 matrix.